# Is there a term like "apparent magnitude" but for things outside of astronomy and depicting area instead of brightness?

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a word that exactly describes the following idea: basically, there's an obvious and simple relationship between how large something is, how far away from it you are, and how large it appears to you. I want the term for how large it appears. Another way to think of this would be how much of your visual real estate it's taking up.

The closest term I could think of was "apparent magnitude" from astronomy, which measures how bright stars *look*, regardless of what their actual size or brightness is. I would like the same idea but for area. For instance, a mug held 3 inches from your eyes will have a higher (blank) than a car sitting 1000 feet away from you.

Anyone know what this might be called? I'm sure there has to be a term for it. This might be the wrong forum but I don't know what science forum would be right.

Comment: If anyone is seeking an explanation of the phenomenon referred to, this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMiKyfd6hA0 - is obligatory

Comment: _Parallax_ appears to be the word you're after.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have never even heard of this show, but AMAZING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**visual angle**

> **Visual angle** is the angle a viewed object subtends at the eye, usually stated in degrees of arc. It also is called the object's
> **angular size**.
> ...
> If one looks at a one-centimeter object at a distance of one meter and
> a two-centimeter object at a distance of two meters, both subtend the
> same **visual angle** of about 0.01 rad or 0.57°. Thus they have the same
> **retinal image size**. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_angle)

> The angle formed by two rays of light or two straight lines drawn from
> the extreme points of a viewed object to the nodal point of the eye.
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/visual%20angle)

Obviously you can apply visual angle to any area/measurement, e.g., height, width, diameter etc.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! It has the added bonus of being completely unambiguous which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ‘field of view’, but I don’t know if it would be higher. If anything, it would be lower and not higher for a mug held close to your face.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).